# Getting an error 'integer expression expected', while comparing two integers

Tags: bash, if-statement, notifications, type-conversion, pandaboard

**# Program which notifies the User through 'notify-send' when device temperature exceeds the threshold.**

```
#!/bin/bash

Temp=adb shell cat /sys/devices/platform/omap/omap_temp_sensor.0/temperature
if  [ $Temp -gt 42000 ] 
then
notify-send Temperature "$Temp " -i /usr/share/pixmaps/idle.xpm
cvlc  /home/Xme/Desktop/Beep-263732.mp3
else
echo "Exit"
fi
```

**Getting error as**

```
: integer expression expected
```

I am not getting the data type of **$Temp** which is reading the data by Device, and how can i compare the integers, i tried `if [ [$Temp > 42000] ]` did not work.

Comment: @fedorqui : Fixed and posted, can anyone please help me out with this.

Comment: What if you do `Temp=$(adb shell cat /sys/devices/platform/omap/omap_temp_sensor.0/temperature)`?

Comment: I am using `Panda board` which is a Mobile Device, through the above command i am reading Temperature, that gives me device current temperature ( Ex:42000 ), i need to compare that value with threshold and if that Temperature exceeds, program will notify me through notify-send command

Comment: Yes, I understood that. What I suggested is to replace Temp definition with `Temp=$(adb shell cat /sys/devices/platform/omap/omap_temp_sensor.0/temperature)`

Comment: Getting same error, `: integer expression expected`

Comment: What kind of data do you get? Are you sure it is just an integer? Try to `Temp=$(adb shell cat /sys/devices/platform/omap/omap_temp_sensor.0/temperature) | grep -o "[0-9]*")` so the output will be just numbers, and hence an integer.

Comment: @fedorqui, Problem solved!! Thank you very much , If possible can you explain what that `grep -o "[0-9]*"` did,  is this conversion to Integer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we said in the comments, this solved the issue:

```
Temp=$(adb shell cat /sys/devices/platform/omap/omap_temp_sensor.0/temperature) | grep -o "[0-9]*")
```

First of all, you were not fetching the number properly. Note that you need to use

```
Temp=$(command)
```

While you were using

```
Temp=command
```

Then we saw that your input was not integer. I guess there must be some trailing characters. To delete them, I suggest to use `grep -o "[0-9]*"`, which just matches the numbers in the string given. EXamples:

```
$ echo "23 " | grep -o "[0-9]*"
23
$ echo "as23.22" | grep -o "[0-9]*"
23
22
$ echo "23" | grep -o "[0-9]*"
23
```